# Show loader during PHP processing after an HTML form submission

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML form like the one shown below, which after submitting is processed by PHP:

```
<form action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="decisions_form">

    <!-- ... -->

    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Decisions" id="decisions_button">
    </div>

</form>
```

PHP does some processing, which could take a few seconds. After processing is complete, I refresh the page as below (probably not best practice, I don't know):

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // PHP...
    }
    echo ('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.1;">');
?>
```

I would like to show a full-screen "loader/spinner", which would be activated after submitting and during PHP processing. Normally, If I understand it correctly, this loader/spinner should be interrupted by the refresh page command -- which is what I want

Looking for such loaders was unsuccessful, if not totally confusing for a inexperienced person like me.

It would be ideal if I could avoid JS and do it in a pure HTML/CSS fashion (is it even possible?).

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a mechanism to do it in pure HTML. There are probably other and more sophisticated ways to do it than what I show below, but this worked well for me. Every time you place a call to the server, the ajax start function executes and delays 1 second (change the delay however you want) and then displays the waiting gif.  When the ajaxStop function is called upon completion of the server call and stops the wait gif and enables the buttons.  Note this should be the first tag in your html file after the css definitions.

Javascript code

```
<script defer>

$( document ).ready(function() {

    // gif on 1 second timer delay before displaying, so user does not have it appear to quickly if the delay is short.
    var loadingTimer;
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        $(':button').prop('disabled', true); // disable all the buttons
        loadingTimer = setTimeout("$('#process-wait').show()", 1000); // show the waiting gif
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        clearTimeout(loadingTimer);
        $("#process-wait").hide(); // hide the waiting gif
        $(':button').prop('disabled', false); // enable all the buttons
    });
});

</script>
```

Here is the css you need to go along with that.  You can make it as big as you want, by adjusting the height and width values.  Pick your own gif image simply set the url parameter to the directory path and name of the gif file.

```
#process-wait {
background: transparent url(images/process-wait.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
z-index: 99999;
display:none;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 0px;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but I don't get it; apologies, newbie here. I tried that in the html file, but it doesn't work. Is there any details I'm missing here? How does the js code "understand" when a form has been submitted?

Comment: As I stated before, I do not believe there is a way to do this with pure html. You will have to add some javascript to your html file.  I have updated my answer to include the javascript html tags.  I recommend you read the W3 Schools javascript tutorials at https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp. and at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example:

```php
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($_SERVER);
        exit;
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div hidden class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
</div>
<form action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="decisions_form">

    <input type="text" name="dummy" value="dummy value">
    <!-- ... -->

    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Decisions" id="decisions_button">
    </div>

</form>
<div class="complete" hidden>
  Submission received<br>
  <button class="reset">Reset</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-oesi62hOLfzrys4LxRF63OJCXdXDipiYWBnvTl9Y9/TRlw5xlKIEHpNyvvDShgf/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const decisionsForm = document.querySelector('#decisions_form');
    const spinner = document.querySelector('.spinner-border');
    const complete = document.querySelector('.complete');
    const resetButton = document.querySelector('.reset');

    // Show spinner, hide form
    function formSending() {
      spinner.removeAttribute('hidden');
      decisionsForm.style.display = 'none';
    }

    // Hide spinner, show complete message
    function formSent() {
      complete.removeAttribute("hidden");
      spinner.setAttribute("hidden", true);
    }

    // Show form, hide everything else
    function reset() {
      decisionsForm.style.display = 'block';
      spinner.setAttribute("hidden", true);
      complete.setAttribute("hidden", true);
    }

    // Send form data in the background
    async function submitDecisionsForm(event) {
      // Display spinner
      formSending();

      // Collect data to send
      // event.target = the form
      // event.target.action the action property on <form action="">
      // the POST body gets set by reading the data from the form object (event.target)
      const response = await fetch(event.target.action, {method: "POST", body: new FormData(event.target)});

      // Submit is complete.. show the complete message and reset button
      formSent();

      // Format the response if you want to use it later
      const responseJson = await response.json(); // or response.text() depending on what send back from the server

      // Output to browser's dev console for debugging
      console.log(text);
    }

    // Capture submit event
    decisionsForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
      // Stop form from submitting immediately by default
      event.preventDefault();

      // Send form data in the background
      submitDecisionsForm(event);
    });

    // demo: reset the form when clicking the reset button
    resetButton.addEventListener('click', reset);
  });
</script>
```

See comments in the code for explanation of parts.